# How to Session::flash with default AuthController in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

After hour wasted on such a (as I thought) minor thing, I need Your help.

I've made a quickstart with Laravel using `php artisan make:auth` command. Then I redefined `login` method in `AuthController`. Now it looks like this:

```
protected function login(Request $request) {
    if (Auth::attempt(["name" => $request->username, "password" => $request->password])) {
        return Redirect::route("home")->with("message", "Zalogowano");
    } else {
        return Redirect::route("get.login")->with("message", "Nie zalogowano");
    }
}
```

In my view I've got`{{ Session::get("message") or "" }}`

and my message doesn't show up.

I've also tried `Session::flash("message", "message string")`, same effect.

Any ideas what could I do to show a message after (un)successfull login?

PS. Should've mention logging in and out works just fine.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using ?

Comment: You can try `{{ session('message') }}`

Comment: Try {{ (isset($message)) ? $message : '' }} in your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your routes defined within the `'web'` middleware group (including the Auth routes)? The `'web'` middleware group handles starting the session.  More specifically the middleware `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` handles starting the session.  No session, no messages.  Your routes should be wrapped in the Route group like so:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
  // Define routes here
});
```

Take a look in `app\Http\Kernel.php` to see what Middleware classes are included in this Middleware group and dive into them.

Comment: Well you were almost right. The problem was with my routes, but the thing is, you can't declare them in web middleware, because routes are set in it by default. My error was declaring routes twice. `php artisan route:list` was helpful. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Ah!  I've made that mistake before.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try {{ $message }} in your template.

When you use ->with("varnamehere", "value") to flash data on the end of your redirect, you can simply access the variable in your template with $varnamehere.

The variable simply exists, ready for use in your template.

There doesn't seem to be a section in the manual that clearly explains this.

Answer (score 0):

In your view template try:

@if (session()->has('message') ? session()->get('message') : "") @endif

It will print the message if is set..

Hope it helps..